# Using Pop up and keep the form open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I try to use pop up to calling my form, it works but every time I pick a value on combo box (onchange action), the form won't keep open so I have to click that pop up again (the value is retain though)
any idea?
here's the code:

```
<head>
    <title>JQuery Popup | JQuery Slide Popup | Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
        <a onclick="openOffersDialog();">Click Here To See The PopUp</a>
        <div id="boxpopup" class="box">
            <a onclick="closeOffersDialog('boxpopup');" class="boxclose"></a>
            <div id="content">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <title>Info Tarif</title>
                    </head>
                    <?php include('connection.php'); ?>
                    <body>
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT distinct (kota_kabupaten) FROM `ongkirjne` order by kota_kabupaten ASC  "; 
                        $result = mysql_query($query); 
                    ?> 
                    <form name="satu" method=GET action="index.php" openOffersDialog();>
                        Pilih Daerah Tujuan :
                        <select name="kota"  onChange='this.form.submit();'>        
                            <option value="">-Pilih Kota/Kabupaten-</option>; 
                            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  { ?>
                                <option <?php if($_REQUEST['kota'] == $row['kota_kabupaten']) echo "selected" ?> ><?php echo $row['kota_kabupaten']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        Pilih Kecamatan :
                        <select name='kec' class='nama' Method='GET'>       
                        <?php
                            echo"<option value>-Pilih Kecamatan-</option>";
                            $city= $_GET['kota'];
                            if (isset($_GET['kota']))
                            {                             
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM `ongkirjne` where kota_kabupaten like '%$city%'"; 
                                $result = mysql_query($query); 
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
                                    <option <?php if($_REQUEST['kec'] == $row['kecamatan']) echo "selected" ?> > 
                                    <?php echo $row['kecamatan'];  ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>         
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>  Berat : <input type="text" name="berat" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['berat']); ?>"/>   
                        <?php
                            echo " <input type='submit' name='hitung' value='hitung' onclick='hitung()'/>";
```

my desire result are:
1. when I click the pop up link, the form shows (ok)
2. when I pick the value on first combo box, the form retain (fail) -> using on change action.
3. when I pick the value on first combo box, the value retain (ok)
4. when I click submit button(hitung), the value retain and the function works (ok)
I want all of them on the same page.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your problem is I believe it can be fixed by just not having any code that hides the form.

Are you using the `.toggle` function? If so, change that to `.show`

If you'd like the form to be hidden again after it's submitted then that will be done automatically when the page refreshes (given you're not using AJAX). You can set the action to "#" for the page to redirect to itself instead of another file.

Comment: I'm not using any .toggle
here's the [link] (http://kliknklik.net/infotarif/pop)
the form disappear when the first combo box value selected, but the value retain if you click the pop up url again.

thanks